# Merge recordset values in SQL query

Tags: sql, merge, recordset

Given the following result set:

[image]

I want to merge:

1. 'Verifying' and 'Verified' rows as Verification_stage,
2. 'Reviewing' and 'Reviewed' rows as Reviewing_stage and
3. 'Analyzing' and 'Analyzed' rows as Analysis_stage
4. Have the respective integers summarized

so I get the following resultset in stead:

```
HAUT-53 | Verification_stage | 677.579 | 6
HAUT-53 | Reviewing_stage    | 516.409 | 2
HAUT-53 | Open               | 70.629  | 1
HAUT-53 | Implementing       | 7       | 1
HAUT-53 | Analysis_stage     | 12.027  | 2
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Show us the column names.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `case` expression to merge, in a derived table. Then `GROUP BY` its result:

```
select c1, c2, sum(c3), sum(c4)
from
(
    select c1, 
           case when c2 in ('Verifying', 'Verified') then 'Verification_Stage'
                when c2 in ('Reviewing', 'Reviewed') then 'Reviewing_Stage'
                when c2 in ('Analyzing', 'Analyzed') then 'Analyzing_Stage'
                else c2 
           end c2,
           c3, c4
    from tablename
) dt
group by c1, c2
```

Using a derived table (the sub-query), means that you don't have to repeat the case expression. Less error prone, easier to maintain - and also ANSI SQL compliant!

Comment: All solutions worked. I choose this one as it is compact and yet readable. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's your query. You can aggregate your `column3` using `sum()`. Then `group by` stages.

```
select col1, 
    , case when col2 in ('Verifying', 'Verified') then 'Verification_Stage'
        when col2 in ('Reviewing', 'Reviewed') then 'Reviewing_Stage'
        when col2 in ('Analyzing', 'Analyzed') then 'Analyzing_Stage'
        else col2 end
    , sum(col3) 
    , sum(col4)
from tableA
group by col1,
    case when col2 in ('Verifying', 'Verified') then 'Verification_Stage'
        when col2 in ('Reviewing', 'Reviewed') then 'Reviewing_Stage'
        when col2 in ('Analyzing', 'Analyzed') then 'Analyzing_Stage'
        else col2 end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use several `case` expressions, and turn on aggregation. You did not give the name of your columns so I assumed `col1, col2, col3, col4`.

```
select
    col1,
    case 
        when col2 in ('Verifying', 'Verified') then 'Verification_stage'
        when col2 in ('Reviewing', 'Reviewed') then 'Reviewing_stage'
        when col2 in ('Analyzing', 'Analyzed') then 'Analysis_stage'
        else col2
    end new_col2
    max(col3) max_col3,
    sum(col4) sum_col4
from mytable
group by 
    col1,
    case 
        when col2 in ('Verifying', 'Verified') then 'Verification_stage'
        when col2 in ('Reviewing', 'Reviewed') then 'Reviewing_stage'
        when col2 in ('Analyzing', 'Analyzed') then 'Analysis_stage'
        else col2
    end
```

If there are no other values than the ones you listed, this can be shortened as follows:

```
select
    col1,
    case 
        when col2 like 'Verif%' then 'Verification_stage'
        when col2 like 'Review%' then 'Reviewing_stage'
        when col2 like 'Analyz%' then 'Analysis_stage'
        else col2
    end new_col2
    max(col3) max_col3,
    sum(col4) sum_col4
from mytable
group by 
    col1,
    case 
        when col2 like 'Verif%' then 'Verification_stage'
        when col2 like 'Review%' then 'Reviewing_stage'
        when col2 like 'Analyz%' then 'Analysis_stage'
        else col2
    end
```

Side note: few RDBMS support column aliases in the `group by` clause (MySQL is an example); this gives you the opportunity to shorten the `group by` clause:

```
group by col1, new_col2
```